# How to keep certain levels of a categorical variable and set remaining as "other" in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, d1 and d2, both with the same categorical variables. However, the categories of a particular variable might be different.

For example, for variable v1 in data frame d1, we have the following categories or levels: "a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e"
and for the same variable v1, in data frame d2 we have levels: "a", "b", "c"

I want to then transform v1 in data frame d1 such that the only the levels common with d2 remain and the rest are relabeled as "other", i.e., d1["v1"] should be transformed to: "a", "b", "c", "other", "other"

Both data frames have over 4 million observations and hence I am looking for a fast way to do this.

Example below:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(1, 11), "v1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "e", "d", "a", "d"]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(1, 11), "v1": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a"]})
d1
   id v1
0   1  a
1   2  b
2   3  c
3   4  d
4   5  e
5   6  a
6   7  e
7   8  d
8   9  a
9  10  d

[10 rows x 2 columns]

d2
   id v1
0   1  a
1   2  b
2   3  c
3   4  a
4   5  c
5   6  b
6   7  c
7   8  a
8   9  b
9  10  a

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

After transformation, new d1 should look like:

```
d1
    id     v1
0   1      a
1   2      b
2   3      c
3   4  other
4   5  other
5   6      a
6   7  other
7   8  other
8   9      a
9  10  other

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
d1.ix[~d1.v1.isin(d2.v1.unique()), 'v1'] = 'other'
```

**Edit** On reflection, an explanation would be good too. :)

- `d2.v1.unique()` - select unique values in `d2.v1`
- `d1.v1.isin()` - find those values in `d1.v1`
- `d1.ix[~..., 'v1']` - invert, select rows that match condition and change `v1` column on those rows

**Edit 2** Sorry, my original answer changed both rows in `d1` to `other`. Updated.